# How to style with SASS

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

The Getting Started guide notes:

> There are several ways to include the Kendo UI theme in your project. We recommend Webpack and its Sass loader, which allows the customization of the Kendo UI theme by using Sass variables.
>
> Let’s do something simpler for now, though.

So how do we do the more complex version with Webpack and Sass?

Comment: This can be helpful http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elaborate guide on styling the Kendo UI for Angular 2 components can be found in the [themes documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/#build-custom-themes). The [general advice by Maloric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39992634/25427) still applies -- you can see a working sample that uses the components in the [ng2-dashboard app](https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard) ([scss](https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard/blob/master/web/app/app.style.scss), [component](https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard/blob/master/web/app/app.component.ts#L6-L11), [webpack.config](https://github.com/telerik/ng2-dashboard/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L177-L185)).

Comment: Thanks. Between you and @Maloric I think I'm on the right path now.

Answer (score 2):

**Angular CLI**

If you're starting a new project, I would recommend the Angular CLI over WebPack, as the CLI uses WebPack behind the scenes anyway.  To install, type the following command:

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

The Angular CLI gives you a lot of helper commands to generate new components etc.  For a comprehensive list of commands, see the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular2-project-via-a-development-server).

To create a new project using SASS, use the following command in your terminal / command prompt:

```
ng new myProjectName --style=sass
```

You then simply reference the scss file from your component instead of a css file.  The CLI will handle compilation of the stylesheet for you.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom-component',
    templateUrl: './my-custom.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-custom.component.scss'], // Angular CLI knows this is a sass file and will preprocess it appropriately
})
export class MyCustomComponent {

}
```

Remember that your stylesheets are scoped, so you can write a style rule with the selector `div` and it will only apply to divs inside this component (not even in descendants).  If you want to reference styles outside the component, use the [special selectors found in the Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#special-selectors), such as `:host-context(.myClass)` or `/deep/`.

---

**WebPack**

If you'd prefer to use WebPack without the Angular CLI, you'll need to install the `sass-loader` package:

```
npm install sass-loader --save-dev
```

You then need to configure the plugin inside of your webpack.config.  Add the following to the module.loaders section of the config:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
}
```

Full documentation for using the sass-loader plugin can be found on the [sass-loader GitHub page](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#usage).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using Angular CLI. I just wasn't sure how to get styles to apply within a component – whether I had to do anything with the main styles file. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Added some clarification regarding getting styles working on a component.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thanks.